# Angular form submitting

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new in programming and need a little advice.

I create two tables in my database - **Employee** (with foreign key "**emp_depId**") and **Department** with values (HR, Tech, Finance). In order to create an employee I need  emp_depId, but from select in my form I get **depName**. What can I do? I must send a request to the server and get all departments from DB and than in data binding call method with "depName" argument, which return me necessary Id. Than I'll assign it to employee.emp_DepId and save.
Here is my form:

```
<form novalidate #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(form)" (reset)="resetForm()" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="employee.firstName" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="lastName" [(ngModel)]="employee.lastName" required />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Department</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="depName" [(ngModel)]="getDepId(department.depName)">
                <option  *ngFor="let depName of getDepartments(); let i = index" [value] = "depName[i]">
                    {{depName}}
                </option>
            </select>
    </div>      
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
        [class.btn-warning]="editing" [disabled]="form.invalid">
        {{editing ? "Save" : "Create"}}
        </button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary" routerLink="/">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Am I right?  Thank you.

Comment: Get both `depName` and `depId` from the database. Then put `depId` into the value of the `<option>`.

Comment: Whats the output of getDepartments() ?

Comment: The output of getDepartments() - "HR", "Tech", "Finance"  with id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code you can do it like :

```
<select class="form-control" name="emp_DepId" [(ngModel)]="employee.emp_DepId">
    <option  *ngFor="let depName of getDepartments(); let i = index" [value] = "getDepId(depName)">
        {{depName}}
    </option>
</select>
```

---

But ideally it should be like this :

```
// output of getDepartments() should look like this
[
    { id : 1 , name : 'department 1'},
    { id : 2 , name : 'department 2'}
    { id : 3 , name : 'department 3'}
]

<select class="form-control" name="emp_DepId" [(ngModel)]="employee.emp_DepId">
    <option  *ngFor="let dep of getDepartments(); let i = index" [value] = "dep.id">
        {{dep.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: I understand. Thank you